# Empty ssl certificate list in azure website

Tags: azure, ssl, web, ssl-certificate, azure-web-app-service

I need to add an SSL certificate to my site. My web hosting plan in "basic".

I added the site. I added the SSL certificate. But I don't see it in list.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the binding between the domain and the certificate. It's right there in your screenshot: **enable ssl bindings**.

Comment: I've chosen my domain name and the "Choose a certificate" drop down is still empty.